# Remove Vim blank line under the command line

Tags: vim, terminal

I'v been using Vim for a few months now and I just noticed this blank line under the command line. I tried to remove it but couldn't succeed.

I tried to do `:set cmdheight=1` but it did not change anything. When I set it to more than One, it expands normally

Is there a way to get rid of this line ?

I use i3 running on a X server, but I only get this line using Vim

I use [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/) status bar

With `set cmdheight=1`

[image: Screenshot]

And with `set cmdheight=3` :

[image]

Comment: did you try put the `set cmdheight=1` into your vimrc?

Comment: Yep, changed nothing

Comment: Hmm, could you please try `:verbose set cmdheight?` . You can see where is the part set the value.

Comment: `cmdheight=1 Last set from ~/.vimrc`

Comment: Strange. how about to set cmdheight=5 or greater? The problem occur only when cmdheight=1?

Comment: What's the value of `set cmdheight?` returned

Comment: `set cmdheight` returns `cmdheight=1`

Comment: @mattn If i put more than 1, the number of lines grows just well

Comment: @Gyldhas what is the 1..2.. underneath vim? tmux ? or what? which terminal do you use?

Comment: It's i3, The 1..2.. are the two workspaces I use. 

The terminal is urxvt. The problem may come from the `utf-8` characters vim-airline uses and that urxvt struggles to render...

Comment: Oh, problem solved. Posting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured the answer.

I use the `urxvt` terminal, with some Perl scripts.
One of these scripts allows me to dynamicaly set the font height of the terminal (e.g. in a few keystrokes I can increase the font size)

And because I "zoomed", the last line was too short to contain a full character line. So it was displayed black.

Example :

Vanilla zoom, no black line :

[image]

A bit of zoom (note the black line appearing, but too small to contain a full character)

[image]

More zoom

[image]

So there is no other solution than "zoom differently" or "deal with it"